# Can't display phplot with foreach $user (height, weight)

Tags: laravel, phplot

I want to make a Scatterplot with phplot and laravel so i get all user with height, weight but they just show 2 point/52 user. I don't know why please help me.

```
  $users = User::all();
    $maxHeight = $users->filter()->max('height');
    $maxWeight = $users->filter()->max('weight');
    $data = array();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $data[] = array('', (int)$user->height, (int)$user->weight);
    }

    $plot = new PHPlot(800, 600);
    $plot->SetImageBorderType('plain');

    $plot->SetPlotType('points');
    $plot->SetDataType('data-data');

    # Main plot title:
    $plot->SetTitle('Scatterplot (User plot)');

    $plot->SetXTitle('weight');
    $plot->SetYTitle('height');
    $plot->SetDataValues($data);

    # Need to set area and ticks to get reasonable choices.
    $plot->SetPlotAreaWorld(0, 0, $maxWeight, $maxHeight);
    $plot->SetXTickIncrement(5);
    $plot->SetYTickIncrement(5);

    $plot->SetYTickPos('yaxis');


    # Turn on 4 sided borders, now that axes are inside:
    $plot->SetPlotBorderType('full');

    # Draw both grids:
    $plot->SetDrawXGrid(True);
    $plot->SetDrawYGrid(True);  # Is default

    $plot->SetIsInline(true);
    $plot->SetOutputFile("test.png");

    $plot->DrawGraph();
```

Then they just show 2 point with 2 user but not all:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwbKn.png)

Comment: Does every user have height and weight ?

Comment: yess. https://prntscr.com/1hk0cx1 they already have.